# How can we do Dense Rank on a field in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, rank

I am trying to dense rank a field, from the highest number (lowest rank) to the lowest number (highest rank). I tried this.

```
df['DenseRank'] = df['CountsOfCircuits'].rank(ascending=False)
```

The max number I have in 'CountsOfCircuits' is 804. I want this to be ranked as 1, but I'm getting 402.50! How can I dense rank a field, with the top number having a dense rank of 1 and the bottom having the max dense rank?

Comment: Can't tell why you're getting 402.50 without knowing what the data looks like, but the default behavior of [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) is to average the rank. You'll want to change the `method` parameter.

Comment: You are correct! The method parameter controls it. Now, I'm using this.

df_upper['DenseRank'] = df_upper.CountsOfCircuits.rank(method='dense').astype(int)

That ranks the lowest count as 1 as the highest one as 18. I was trying to do the opposite, but I haven't been able to get it working just yet.

Comment: Did you forget the `ascending = False`?

Comment: This works!!

df_upper['DenseRank'] = df_upper.CountsOfCircuits.rank(method='dense').astype(int)